Identify a locator by partial class name
I have the following element, where the first part is always constant (_wrapper_) but the 2nd part (12npv_9) always changes its value after a new build
<div class="_wrapper_12npv_9">

I want to write a locator that will always select the first part of the class name and does not take into account the 2nd part. So far i have this but it is displaying the error "Cannot find name '_wrapper_'"
await page.locator('div[contains(@class,'_wrapper_')]')

How can i make it so that is only takes into account the first constant part of the class name, which is '_wrapper_' ?

page.locator('[class^="_wrapper_"]') should work, assuming class="_wrapper_12npv_9" is the whole class name. Note that await is only necessary for locators when they have an action added to them, like .click().

All: Please note that this is a question about locating elements in Playwright, specifically, and not just about CSS selectors.

Does this answer your question? Match all elements having class name starting with a specific string

Generally speaking, don't use CSS selectors in Playwright tests because they're not user-visible. If you provide more context for what you're trying to accomplish (actual site, expected output), this would be more specific to Playwright. But as you've only shown a CSS selector (possibly an XY problem), the question does reduce to this.

The solution from your first comment is what i have been looking for. Thanks!

page.locator can accept either CssSelector or XPath and identify by itself which one did you enter. 
Here you're trying to enter an XPath, and here's your problem:
// Wrong - Missing "//" at the beginning and uses single quotes within single quotes
await page.locator('div[contains(@class,'_wrapper_')]')

// Correct
await page.locator("//div[contains(@class, '_wrapper_')"]

In addition - in this case it's better to use starts-with instead of contains like so:
await page.locator("//div[starts-with(@class, '_wrapper_')"]

